# Restricting access to localhost for Java Servlet endpoint

Tags: java, servlets

*In short* - I would like to add such service endpoints to my servlet that can only be called from localhost. The restriction should be coded in the servlet itself, i.e it should not depend on Tomcat/Apache to be configured in a certain way. At the same time, there are many other, existing endpoints that should be reachable externally.

*Longer description* - I am creating an HTTP API that 3rd parties can implement to integrate with my application. I am also supplying a default implementation, bundled together with my app, that customers with simple requirements can use, without having to implement anything.

The endpoints of my default implementation should be reachable only for my app, which happens to be the same servlet as the one supplying the implementation, i.e it runs on the same host. So for security reasons (the API is security related), I want my implementation to be usable only for my app, which in the first round means restricting access to localhost for a set of HTTP endpoints.

At the same time, I don't want to rely on customers setting up their container/proxy properly, but do the restriction in my servlet, so that there are no changes required for existing installations.

So far the only idea I had was to check the requestor's IP addess in a servlet filter - so I am wondering if there is a better, more sophisticated way.

Comment: Basically, you want to restrict access based on `request.getRemoteAddr()` from the WAR on? If so, a servlet filter is indeed most sophisticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add Web Filter to your application and check your url in doFilter method. Check request.getRemoteAddr() and endpoint link you can put in urlPattern.

Like this:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*")
public class RequestDefaultFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (isForbidden(request, response))
                return;
        else
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

isForbidden implementation is up to you. In response you just send 403 error code for example.

You can check make same check in servlet and send in response 403 error.